# I was trying to push my project to github from goormIDE container, but fails with the authentication

Tags: github

I and tried pushing my to github. I have added and committed all my files properly. then i run the command

git remote add origin "url"

then I did

```
git push origin master
```

Then it asks for authentication.

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

I enter the username and after this it asks for password. But then it does not allow me to enter my password.Anything i press on the keyboard does not get reflected to the screen. Does any any else also face this problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you enter passwords - they are not reflected in the screen by design. It's about extra security. See more [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/268006/why-is-the-password-i-entered-not-visible).